# Can mobile workers view case data from multiple locations?

Tags: commcare

In my application cases are configured to be owned by locations-- in this case, villages. Mobile workers can work in multiple villages and need to be able to see case details from each of the villages to which they are assigned.

Is it possible for mobile workers to view case data from multiple locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign multiple locations to users, they'll be able to see cases associated with any of their assigned locations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can assign multiple locations to user. For mobile workers assigned to locations that can "View Child Data", they can sometimes be in more than one case sharing group. The user will be required to choose which location the case gets assigned to. For example, a clinic may be required to register clients and assign them to one of their CHWs.